# Два TextView в одну строку

Tags: android, layout

Делаю макет айтема для ExpandableView, состоящий из двух TextView на одном уровне. При этом, хочу чтобы левый был прижат к левому краю макета, а правый - к правому. Правый всегда короткий, т.к. там только 5-7знаков, а левый может быть длинным, поэтому он с возможностью переноса.

Проблема у меня в том, что мне не удается все сделать красиво. Тексты либо наезжают друг на друга, либо не прижимаются к краям, либо вообще обрезаются О_о
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это при том, что на макете выглядит пристойно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К сожалению. кода этой разметки не сохранил, вот текущая, после множественных экспериментов:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/diary_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="Title Logggg Title Looongeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colour_text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/diary_qty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="@string/child_qty"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textColor="@color/colour_text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Перепробовал много чего, что казалось подходящим, и уже замучился.
Посоветуйте грамотную разметку.

Подчеркну дополнительно - проблема вылезает именно в случае использования макета в качестве разметки айтема раскрывающегося списка (ExpandableListView). Как грамотно строить чилдрен ExpandableListView?

Код Активити и Адаптера вот такие:

TMPActivity.java:

```
package org.zav.food;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import org.zav.food.MyTypes.TextPare;
import org.zav.food.adapter.MyExpandableListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TMPActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyExpandableListAdapter mExpListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tmp_exp);

        List<String> ExpandableList_group_List = new ArrayList<>(5);
        ExpandableList_group_List.add("Завтрак");
        ExpandableList_group_List.add("Обед");
        ExpandableList_group_List.add("Полдник");
        ExpandableList_group_List.add("Ужин");
        ExpandableList_group_List.add("Хватит жрать!");
        List<TextPare> ExpandableList_children_List = new ArrayList<>(5);
        ExpandableList_children_List.add(new TextPare("Картошка", "100г"));
        ExpandableList_children_List.add(new TextPare("Хрен", "100г"));
        ExpandableList_children_List.add(new TextPare("масло", "100г"));
        ExpandableList_children_List.add(new TextPare("Йад", "100г"));

        final ExpandableListView ExpandableEatenToday = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list_0);
        mExpListAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this);
        ExpandableEatenToday.setAdapter(mExpListAdapter);

        mExpListAdapter.Parents.addAll(ExpandableList_group_List);

        // Пока заполняю хардкодово
        // Надо будет заполнять данными из базы по кнопке Add
        mExpListAdapter.Children1.addAll(ExpandableList_children_List);
        mExpListAdapter.Children1.add(new TextPare("ХЗ", "0г"));

        //обновляю отображение листа
        mExpListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

MyExpandableListAdapter.java:

```
package org.zav.food.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.zav.food.MyTypes.TextPare;
import org.zav.food.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public List<String> Parents = new ArrayList<>();

    //жестко задал 5 групп (приемов пищи).
    //Каждая группа имеет свой список продуктов
    public List<TextPare> Children0 = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<TextPare> Children1 = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<TextPare> Children2 = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<TextPare> Children3 = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<TextPare> Children4 = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        switch (groupPosition){
            case 0:
                return Children0.get(childPosition);
            case 1:
                return Children1.get(childPosition);
            case 2:
                return Children2.get(childPosition);
            case 3:
                return Children3.get(childPosition);
            case 4:
                return Children4.get(childPosition);

            default: return null;
        }
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        // в зависимости от номера группы, смотрю размер листа соответствующей группы
        switch (groupPosition){
            case 0:
                return Children0.size();
            case 1:
                return Children1.size();
            case 2:
                return Children2.size();
            case 3:
                return Children3.size();
            case 4:
                return Children4.size();

            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public TextView getGenericView()
    {
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Center the text vertically
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        // Set the text starting position
        textView.setPadding(55, 0, 0, 0);
        return textView;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return Parents.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        return Parents.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }


    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_eaten_expandable_group, null);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_eaten_expandable_group, parent, false);

        }

        String group = Parents.get(groupPosition);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_group)).setText(group);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_eaten_expandable_children, null);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_eaten_expandable_children, parent, false);

        switch (groupPosition) {
            case 0: {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_name)).setText(Children0.get(childPosition).getTxtFirst());
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_qty)).setText(Children0.get(childPosition).getTxtSecond());
            } break;

            case 1: {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_name)).setText(Children1.get(childPosition).getTxtFirst());
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_qty)).setText(Children1.get(childPosition).getTxtSecond());
            } break;

            case 2: {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_name)).setText(Children2.get(childPosition).getTxtFirst());
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_qty)).setText(Children2.get(childPosition).getTxtSecond());
            } break;

            case 3: {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_name)).setText(Children3.get(childPosition).getTxtFirst());
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_qty)).setText(Children3.get(childPosition).getTxtSecond());
            } break;

            case 4: {
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_name)).setText(Children4.get(childPosition).getTxtFirst());
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diary_qty)).setText(Children4.get(childPosition).getTxtSecond());
            } break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Класс TextPare:

```
package org.zav.food.MyTypes;

public class TextPare {
    private String mTxtFirst;
    private String mTxtSecond;

    public TextPare() {
    }

    public TextPare(String txtFirst, String txtSecond) {
        mTxtFirst = txtFirst;
        mTxtSecond = txtSecond;
    }

    public String getTxtFirst() {
        return mTxtFirst;
    }

    public void setTxtFirst(String txtFirst) {
        mTxtFirst = txtFirst;
    }

    public String getTxtSecond() {
        return mTxtSecond;
    }

    public void setTxtSecond(String txtSecond) {
        mTxtSecond = txtSecond;
    }
}
```

Comment: что за метод getGenericView()? где и кем он используется и зачем вообще там, ведь вы создаете  айтем через инфлейт xml-разметки ... возможно вам стоит взять более простой пример, напр. с [сайта Климова](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/expandablelistview.php) или с [хабра, с кастомным адаптером](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/147546/)

Comment: getGenericView() не используется. Оставил на будущее, разобраться/научиться. В том обьеме в котором использую я, это предельно просто, кажется. Два текста ) Вам удалось поиграться с моим примером? Как результат?

Answer (score 1):

В общем то у вас все правильно, за исключением двух моментов:

1. Если в "длинном" виджете возможно несколько строк, то "короткий" надо центрировать по середине "длинного", связав верхнюю и нижнюю точки виджетов соответственно, "которткий" при этом не привязывается к краям экрана сверху\снизу.
2. "Длинный" виджет должен быть "привязан" к короткому по горизотали (правый край "длинного" к левому краю "короткого") - не наоборот!

Вот такая разметка получилась у меня (большие маржины для лучшей видимости связей на скриншоте):

[image: scrn]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long some text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Some Text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

"Длинный" виджет имеет длину `match_constraint` и привязывается левым краем к левому краю экрана , правым краем к "короткому" виджету, верхом к краю экрана сверху. "Короткий" виджет имеет длину `wrap_content`, верхом и низом привязывается к верху и низу "длинного" виджета для центровки относительно него, правым краем к правому краю экрана.

Такая разметка будет иметь длину "короткого" виджета равную длине текста в нем, все остальное пространство будет занимать текст "длинного" виджета. Если текст "длинного" дойдет до "короткого", то в длинном будет перенос на другую строку

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Звучит логично, только у меня не сработало. Ни в сравнительно свежем эмуляторе, ни в физическом устройстве с 4.4. Первый текст как будто заруливается в минуса, а второй текст (короткий) прижимается к левому краю. А на проекте макета да, все красиво.

У вас в эмуляторе получилось?

Comment: да, я тестировал на устройстве и все в порядке. вы ничего не меняли, убирали или добавляли в мой пример? возможно вы используете эту разметку вложив ее в другую? или какие отличия в использовании. короткий текст не может прижиматься к левому краю, он привязан только к правому, в "минуса" виджет может уйти только с отрицательным маржином

Comment: Я понял в чем дело. Если запустить активити с этим содержимым, то все в порядке, вид как и ожидалось, так как мне надо. Но, я использую этот макет как макет чилдрена в ExpandableListView. В нем все рассыпается. И как строить  - не понятно.

Comment: если проблема появляется в ExpandableListView, надо добавить в вопрос связанный с ним код, как адаптер этого списка и т.п.

Comment: Добавил в головное сообщение.